# Highcharts: How to display each column as a separate series?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to display the data from my json.

My json file looks like this:

```
0: {OGS: "26", STRM: "1811", ACAD_CAREER: null, YEAR: "2018"}1: {OGS: "4144", STRM: "1801", ACAD_CAREER: null, YEAR: "2018"}2: {OGS: "3935", STRM: "1802", ACAD_CAREER: null, YEAR: "2018"}3: {OGS: "16", STRM: "1812", ACAD_CAREER: null, YEAR: "2018"}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
```

And here's my code:

```
<script>
$(function () {

var categData = [];
var statusACountData = [];
var statusBCountData = [];
var dateVal=[];
var statusVal=[];
var countVal = [];

    var jsonvar = [];
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:37590/get_OGSDataPerTermYear/ORT/2018', function (jsonData) {


               for(i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
               dateVal[i]=jsonData[i].STRM;
              // statusVal[i]=jsonData[i].status;
               countVal[i]=jsonData[i].OGS;                   
            }

    //    jsonData
             console.log(jsonData);
             console.log(countVal);
             console.log(categData);


  //  $(function () {
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: dateVal,
                crosshair: true
            },
            series: [{
                name: dateVal,
                data: countVal
            }]
        });

      //  });
         });
});
</script>
```

The column is not showing and the 4 data which is: 1801 1802 1803 and 1804 only appears in 1 series. I want to make them each series with different data which is OGS number.

Comment: what values are logged when you log    //    jsonData
             console.log(jsonData);
             console.log(countVal);
             console.log(categData);

Comment: what will be in the xAxis and y Axis

Comment: console.log(jsonData);  
-Array(3)0: {OGS: "162", STRM: "1601", ACAD_CAREER: null, YEAR: "2016"}1: {OGS: "39", STRM: "1603", ACAD_CAREER: null, YEAR: "2016"}2: {OGS: "233", STRM: "1602", ACAD_CAREER: null, YEAR: "2016"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)


console.log(countVal); 
- Array(3)0: 1621: 392: 233length: 3__proto__: Array(0)

console.log(categData); nothing is showing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it as you expect (each column is a separate series) you can follow this approach:

1. Prepare `series` and `xAxis.categories` arrays. Each `series.data` array should have an appropriate amount of null points before the one with real value. Something like that:

---

**categories:**

```
["1811", "1801", "1802", "1812"]
```

**series:**

```
[{
  name: "cat - 0",
  data: [2456]
}, {
  name: "cat - 1",
  data: [null, 4144]
}, {
  name: "cat - 2",
  data: [null, null, 3935]
}, {
  name: "cat - 3",
  data: [null, null, null, 2316]
}]
```

2. `plotOptions.column.grouping` should be disabled:

---

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: true,
    categories: categories
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false
    }
  },
  series: series
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ynqjftLk/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.grouping

Comment: hi @woj thanks for this, but is it possible to display the value of STRM which is the 1811 as a unique identifier to be named in series?

Comment: i made it, thanks to you wojciech! i just added this one

Comment: one last question, what will be the best approach for the drilldown for this chart? example if i clicked the 1801 column  with the value of 4144 it will drilldown to Acad_career/OGS/

Comment: It should be a default drilldown. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t8na21eh/.

Comment: can i apply all the drilldown on all columns? example if i clicked any of the ff STRM value (1811,1812,1801,1802) it will drill down and get another json url data

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: can you please check my code below? i already added drilldown but it only shows 1 data. example when i click the year 2018 with the data of 8000 after i click that it should display the school term (STRM) with the divide value of 8000 EX. 1811 value 2000 1812 value 2000 1801 value 3000 1802 value 1000. and in my codes it only display 1811 value of 2000

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du4GK.jpg)Your data is not in right format. If you need to plot `STRM` is x axis , you will need to put them in a separate array and assign it to xAxis.

The yAxis also accepts an array of objects and the object need to have two keys like `name` & `data` where  `data` is an array .

Also `OGS` values are in string , so adding a `+` before `jsonData[i].OGS` will convert it to number.

```js
let jsonData = [{
  OGS: "2456",
  STRM: "1811",
  ACAD_CAREER: null,
  YEAR: "2018"
}, {
  OGS: "4144",
  STRM: "1801",
  ACAD_CAREER: null,
  YEAR: "2018"
}, {
  OGS: "3935",
  STRM: "1802",
  ACAD_CAREER: null,
  YEAR: "2018"
}, {
  OGS: "2316",
  STRM: "1812",
  ACAD_CAREER: null,
  YEAR: "2018"
}]

var categData = [];
var statusACountData = [];
var statusBCountData = [];
var dateVal = [];
var statusVal = [];
var countVal = [];
var jsonvar = [];



for (let i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  dateVal[i] = jsonData[i].STRM;
  countVal.push({
    name: 'someText',
    data: [+jsonData[i].OGS]
  })
}





Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Some Text'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'someTExt'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: dateVal,
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'OGS'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: countVal
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: hi @brk thanks for this, its almost there,

all i want to be dispaly is 1811 1801 1802 1812 <- as 4 Category then 
each value will show in graph and also in Xaxis it will show the 4 Category with the specific data value

Comment: hi, i finally add the name of each STRM in the the series and its specific value, the last problem that i am encountering is the xaxis, i also want to display the 1811, 1801, 1802,1812 to the xaxis

Comment: and i also want to limit to 5 columns to display on my chart, i manage to do that i only want to display 2018 to 2014 but on the legend it shows all the year

Answer (score 0):

can you guys check my code for drilldown? it only display 1 data series right after i clicked the column on the first chart,.

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:37590/get_OGSDataPerTermYear/' + strCampus + "/" + 
 data[i].YEAR, function (jsonDataDrill) {

            const datadrill = jsonDataDrill
            console.log(jsonDataDrill);

            for (d = 0; d < datadrill.length; d++) {
                categories = datadrill[d].STRM

            dataseries.push({
                id: datadrill[d].YEAR,
                name: +datadrill[d].STRM,
                data: [{
                    y: +datadrill[d].OGS
                }]
                })
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide me with `jsonDataDrill ` content or prepare a live demo with the chart settings? Code that you posted above is not enough.